# How to write thread waiting in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a thread that I want to set waiting for a time out, OR a signal from the main thread.

I came up with this. It is not working. Why?

```
import threading
import time

t1 = threading.Lock()
cond = threading.Condition(t1)

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        t1.acquire()
        cond.wait(10)`enter code here`
        t1.release()
        print "%s,%s,%s" % (self.name, self.counter, 3)


# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()

time.sleep(2)
t1.acquire()
cond.notify_all()
```

Comment: It is not working is insufficient for a MCVE... what happens versus what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not releasing the lock in the main thread.
Release it, and it'll work (the thread is reaquiring the lock after the `wait` exists, but since it's acquired already, the thread is locked).

```
# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
time.sleep(2)

t1.acquire()
cond.notifyAll()
t1.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

`time.sleep(2)`  wait less time than `cond.wait(10)` while `t1` is still acquired.

You should remove `time.sleep(2)` and replace it with `thread1.join()` to wait for `thread1` to finish.

> **join([timeout])**
>
> Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until
>   the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally
>   or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout
>   occurs.
>   ([ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html))

Comment: Isn't that exactly the point? That `time.sleep(2)` waits less than `cond.wait(10)` so that the thread can grab the lock and prevent the main thread to continue executing itself?